# How can i wait for each element in a list to update to a certain text using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-testing

Let´s say that i have a list with items with different colors. That list can be updated to only list blue items if i add a parameter. How can i verify that the each item is correct?

```
cy.addParameter('blue'); //Will send graphQL query to fetch the correct items. 

cy.get('data li').each((item)=> {
         cy.wrap(item).should('have.text', ' blue ');
       });
```

This will fail because the items in the list has not been updated before i have the possibility to check each item. It´s possible to wait for the request to finnish, but as the queries saves after the first run that "check" won´t work the second time.

Comment: what error are you getting from cypress with this test code? Timeout?

Comment: No. As the list is populated before i add the parameter and it takes a few seconds for it to update, the cy.get('data li').each iterates through the list before it have updated

Comment: Yes, so what is the error you're getting from cypress? A failed assertion? Many failed assertions? What does it say?

Comment: It will say that not all items in the list have text blue

Comment: If you came up with a different solution please, let us know... if it helped you, please accept my answer. Both could be really useful for other users looking for the same (or a similar) answer 

Comment: am I the only one that finds super weird that Cypress boasts everywhere about "being async aware", "no need to wait everywhere"... BUT at the same time it's unable to elegantly handle this use case?

Comment: @LucasPottersky I know your comment is old, but it inspired me to add a more elegant answer since it seems no one else has.

Answer (score 5):

You must write a recursive promise function and check by yourself the color text, try the following

```
function checkColor(selector, color, maxWait, alreadyWaited = 0) {
  const waitTime = 500;
  // cy.get returns a thenebale
  return cy.get(selector).each((item)=> {
    // it checks the text right now, without unnecessary waitings
    if(!item.text() === color) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }).then(result => {
    if(result) {
      // only when the condition passes it returns a resolving promise
      return Promise.resolve(true);
    }
    // waits for a fixed milliseconds amount
    cy.wait(waitTime);
    alreadyWaited++;
    // the promise will be resolved with false if the wait last too much
    if(waitTime * alreadyWaited > maxWait) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('Awaiting timeout'))
    }
    // returns the same function recursively, the next `.then()` will be the checkColor function itself
    return checkColor(selector, color, maxWait, alreadyWaited);
  });
}

// then, in your test...
cy.addParameter('blue'); //Will send graphQL query to fetch the correct items. 
checkColor('data li', 'blue', 10000).then(result => {
  cy.get('data li').each((item)=> {
    cy.wrap(item).should('have.text', ' blue ');
  });
  // or
  expect(result).to.be(true);
});
```

I tried to comment a much as possible the code refactoring the code I developed for an accepted [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732818/how-do-i-wait-until-a-cookie-is-set/54743229#54743229).

Let me know if you need some more help

**UPDATE**

We ([me](https://github.com/NoriSte) and [Tommaso](https://github.com/allevo)) have written a plugin to help you with this kind of checks, its name is [cypress-wait-until](https://github.com/NoriSte/cypress-wait-until).

Please thank the [Open Source Saturday](https://www.meetup.com/it-IT/Open-Source-Saturday-Milano/) community for that, we developed it during one of them Saturdays

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution without using the `cypress-wait-until` plugin. I think this should suffice for most cases.

```js
// get "array" of elements
cy.get('data li').should(elements => {
  elements.each((i, el) => {
    expect(el.innerText).to.eq('blue');  // retry `cy.get()` if one isn't blue
  });
});
```

Source: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#Should-callback

Without having seen OP's code run, I think it's not working because `cy.get('data li')` is never retried. Cypress doesn't retry because `.each()` doesn't trigger retries on failure.